# kinit error: Realm not local to KDC, DC is in a subdomain

Tags: subdomain, kinit, kerberos

I have a user: `oneuser@EXEMPLE.COM` as principal and the next krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXEMPLE.COM
    default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 
    default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 
    permitted_enctypes   = arcfour-hmac-md5 

[realms]
    EXEMPLE.COM = {
            kdc = DC.SUBDOMAIN.EXEMPLE.COM
            admin_server = DC.SUBDOMAIN.EXEMPLE.COM
            default_domain = EXEMPLE.COM
            }

[domain_realm]
    .EXEMPLE.COM = EXEMPLE.COM
    EXEMPLE.COM = EXEMPLE.COM
```

kinit give's me the error "**Realm not local to KDC while getting initial credentials**". 
What am i doing wrong? Is there any setup i can do in the conf file so i can use de DC located in a subdomain?